# Check C# MVC Linq If a stored date is 7 days away

Tags: c#, linq, date, datetime

In an MVC5 controller Linq Query I want to send a reminder email every day to my clients when it is 7 days to a nominated day.  This date is not a full date it is just the day value of the month  which is stored in mysql database as an int (1 to 28). So I have a hangfire background script that will check this condition every day and send emails to clients that will meet this condition

```
var rem = db.DDs.Where(a => (new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month,a.Day).AddMonths(1)==DateTime.Today.AddDays(7))).ToList();
```

I am not sure if the above query is the best way to do this

Update i have  updated .NOW to .Today  and tested getting this error

Message = "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime AddMonths(Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

Comment: Off the top of my head, I'm not sure that query will actually run. I'm not confident the database adapter for MySQL will be able to compile that complicated where condition into SQL. Have you been able to run it successfully?

Comment: If you're not storing times then you want to use `DateTime.Today` rather than `DateTime.Now` as the latter includes the time so your equality test will always fail unless it runs at exactly midnight.

Comment: [DateTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx) stores a date and time parts!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you can just send mails to clients of which `a.Day` equals an integer value. Since you do this once a day, you'll never send a mail twice:

```
var dayNumber = ....
var rem = db.DDs.Where(a => a.Day == dayNumber);
```

Now the question is: how to determine `dayNumber`?

Obviously, `DateTime.Today.Day` should be used, and then look at `a.Day` values that are 7 days ahead. That would be:

```
dayNumber = DateTime.Today.Day + 7;
```

But what if `DateTime.Today.Day` is `22` or greater? Then `dayNumber = 29`, which is greater than `28`, so you don't send mails. Or do you? In non-leap years, Feb. 22 a week later is March 1, so `dayNumber` should be calculated as `1`. So the number of days in a month should also be taken into  account. The calculation of the right number ends up to be:

```
var date = DateTime.Now;
var daysInMonth = DateTime.DaysInMonth(date.Year, date.Month);
var dayNumber = (date.Day + 6) % daysInMonth + 1;
```

Here, `%` is the modulo operator, for example, `37 % 31 = 6`.

Note that `dayNumber = (date.Day + 7) % daysInMonth` would produce `0` values at each day of a month where `date.Day + 7` equals `daysInMonth`. Hence `date.Day + 6` and the later addition of `1`.

Just some sample output:

```
20-01-16: 27
21-01-16: 28
22-01-16: 29
23-01-16: 30
24-01-16: 31
25-01-16: 1
...
30-01-16: 6
31-01-16: 7
01-02-16: 8
02-02-16: 9
...
20-02-16: 27
21-02-16: 28
22-02-16: 29
23-02-16: 1
24-02-16: 2
...
29-02-16: 7
01-03-16: 8
02-03-16: 9
...
24-03-16: 31
25-03-16: 1
26-03-16: 2
...
31-03-16: 7
01-04-16: 8
02-04-16: 9
```

So, in leap years, like 2016, at Feb. 22 you don't send mails (=> Feb. 29), whereas in non-leap years you would.

Answer (score 0):

Please, read all comments to the question. Usually `DateTime` stores date and time parts. So, you have change your query to:

```
DateTime dbeg = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-7);
DateTime dend = dbeg.AddDays(1).AddSeconds(-1);

var rem = db.DDs.Where(a => a>=dbeg && a<=dend).ToList();
//returns data between: #2016-06-11 00:00:00# and #2016-06-11 23:59:59#
```